# How would I go about compiling an OpenCV program WITHOUT linking?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've taken the "edge" sample file and moved the appropriate source files into the directory, changing #include(s) where needed to account for the directory structure and not being setup with the library and all that. The goal being to make a more portable batch of code to try some things out. I was wondering, given the list of linker errors (lots of undefined this and that.) Would it A, be possible to take the source and include it all in a way that I won't need linking? And if so B, what would be the suggested route to find which source files have the right code to counter all the undefined stuff I get while linking?

I understand this is a general question, but it requires a general answer and I haven't seen anyone answer this here or anywhere else. I would think it's entirely possible though, OpenCV is BSD and all the source to compile it into the library is available, so I would imagine you could skip the linking to an external library step if you had the source for the library in your project code. Thanks a million to whoever can help me out or lead me into the right direction, it's much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. I would definitely recommend fixing your linker errors instead of copying source code out of opencv. If you post your linker errors here, people might be able to help.

Comment: It's not that, I've successfully linked and made plenty of OpenCV stuff, I want to make it portable for various reasons but mostly so that I can make a program and have my brother help me work on it without him (or anyone) needing to setup the OpenCV libraries themselves.

Comment: Why can't your brother set up OpenCV? It is already designed to be portable. If you can use something like cmake for your own code as well, it should be relatively painless to distribute with opencv dependencies. If you have a good reason for wanting to do this, it isn't clear in your question.

Comment: I don't see why I need to justify my question, to me my reasons are perfectly good and to you they are not. If you can't help but are being difficult then move on please.

Advantages to portable OpenCV project that requires no library linking.

1. It takes seconds to share the source and try compiling it instead of having to setup OpenCV first.
2. You can try it out with ANY C++ compiler instead of being stuck using codeblocks like I do.
3. You don't get the issues of having you OpenCV library in a different location on your computer than the other person.

I can't list any more in the comment

Comment: That's fine, I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just trying to understand. I don't know how to do what you want other than by copy/paste and trial and error, but if anyone else has suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I agree this sounds like a bad idea.  If the goal is to make the project easier to share, having OpenCV wrapped up in a library sounds way better than having its source code inside your project, let alone the problems you will have updating to new versions of OpenCV...  If you are worried about setup for OpenCV why not just put all the libraries inside your project directory?  At least then there would be no "setup"

Comment: The  32bit windows installer for OpenCV is 251MB, not sure if that indicates how large the library parts I would need to include in the folder would be but size is another reason for slimming down the code to just what is strictly needed. As for updating, I don't plan on "updating" the project I'm wanting to make along with OpenCV, I plan on splitting off and having it separate from OpenCV entirely. (not planning a fork library, just an entirely separate project.) Also the library-in-folder-method would limit me to just windows lest I include ALL platform's libraries right?

Comment: if you want a specific person to see your comment you should use the @Username feature, otherwise they might never see it.  The OpenCV library I am using is 67MB.  Even if you don't need to update, the ability to upgrade if desired is not worthless.  Say some genius speeds up some algorithms in OpenCV, its great to be able to take advantage of that with little effort.  I have worked on a project that kept the OpenCV library in source control inside the project directory and it worked fine.

Comment: If you are really committed to your goal, good luck, I don't know how to help you.  Just make sure it is what you want.

Comment: @Hammer, thanks for the tip. I'm definitely considering all angles and want to let everyone know I appreciate the help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project requires fully open source code, you can do what you want. Of course, to isolate what you need from OpenCV will be a demanding task. To do that, you need to manually locate the files including the missing objects. In MS explorer you search using "inside the file" query, in linux console you can use "find | grep" combo command.

I sometimes move source files(opencv/modules/*/src) locally in my projects to customize some functions. I also keep the linked libraries which compiler puts second in priority and they become inactive but they still exists in their original form occupying some negligible useless MBs.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark as answered, it's been awhile since I've been here, thanks for the assistance.